# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections PDOException / Database.php:34

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded my big website onto a shared hosting. I don't have any traffic yet but it shows me "too many connections". Is it a problem of hosting or my website internal problem?

Comment: We need to see your my.cnf file if possible. This might be better aimed at your hosting provider asusing a shared hosting. Provider. Usually. Means you're limited on what you can do as one change affects all

Comment: expalin me in detail what is cnf file

Comment: Aim at config file that could have number connection limit. OR you might be having any recursive calls issue in any query.

Comment: i was uploading website on a subdoamin and i have upload sql file in php my admin and its shows me too many connection and i remove the subdomain database and again it is shwoing too may connection i have call to my hosting provider he terminate my cpanel adn renew it and again it is showing too many connection

Comment: can i send u code of my database.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question to fix grammar but what is really missing is some code/config to reproduce the problem. Is this error shown on all pages? If not, please reduce it on a page that shows the error, make the issue reproducible so that we can help you. Best regards

Comment: some times i open my website  and its randomly appear and automatically goes

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect to your host service provider and discuss about this error, generally this error occurs if you reach the limit of max_connections, which points out it is possibly issue on service provider end.

As you already pointed out it is a shared host hence it increases the above mentioned possibility.